# OpenVPN upgrade existing certificates from MD5

Tags: vpn, android, openvpn, certificate, md5

I noticed that when I connect from my phone using OpenVPN I get a message telling me that in April 2018 support for MD5 will be dropped.

Can someone please indicate how to update my existing certificates (or create new ones) that would:

1. Address this issue
2. Allow me to connect from my phone

[image: Screen shot from my Android Phone]

Comment: I managed to solve the problem and I've documented the process in a [HOW TO Article](http://www.alanbonnici.com/2018/01/howto-setup-openvpn-server-and-client.html) that goes through the process of creating the server and client configuration files. Sample ovpn files for both are included. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I've done:

1. Upgrading *easy-rsa*, ensuring I'm correctly use `.cnf` file:

   ```
   cd /path/to/myEasyRsaDir
   grep md openssl.cnf
   ```

   This must print something like

   ```
   default_md      = sha256                # use public key default MD
   ```
2. Rename your old `keys` dir, than create new one:

   ```
   my keys oldkeys
   mkdir keys
   . vars
   mv -i oldkeys/*.key keys/
   ```
3. Updating creating new root CA cert:

   ```
   openssl x509 -in oldkeys/ca.crt -out keys/ca.crt -signkey keys/ca.key
   ```
4. Updating server cert:

   Two steps: building Certificate Signing Request (client side):

   ```
   openssl x509 -x509toreq -in oldkeys/server.crt -signkey keys/server.key \
       -extensions server -out keys/server.csr
   ```

   and signing certificat with CA key:

   ```
   openssl ca -batch -out keys/server.pem  -in keys/server.csr \
      -extensions server -config $KEY_CONFIG -keyfile keys/ca.key
   ```

   then you could drop `.csr` file

   ```
   rm keys/server.csr
   ```
5. Then you could upgrade each clients, same than server:

   Two steps, the first could be done by client itself:

   ```
   openssl x509 -x509toreq -in oldkeys/server.crt -signkey keys/server.key \
       -out keys/server.csr
   ```

   and, from the `.csr` file: signing certificat with CA key:

   ```
   openssl ca -batch -out keys/server.pem  -in keys/server.csr \
      -config $KEY_CONFIG -keyfile keys/ca.key

   rm keys/server.csr
   ```